# x tick labels are not completely turning off

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I am using the following code.

```
days = 1:1:15;
nash=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15];
rew = ones(1,15);
rate  = rew/max(rew);
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(days, nash, days, rate, 'bar', 'plot');
set(get(ax(2), 'Ylabel'), 'String', 'Average Throughput');
set(get(ax(1), 'Ylabel'), 'String', 'Probability of Convergence');

pos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca,'Position',[pos(1), .2, pos(3) .65])
Xt = days;
set(gca,'XTick',Xt);
algos = ['[3  36 24]';'[18 36  9]';'[33 24  6]';'[33 12 18]';'[36 17 10]';
         '[33 20 10]';'[34 24  5]';'[34 12 17]';'[34 20  9]';'[48 12  3]';
         '[48 10  5]';'[48  6  9]';'[40 20  3]';'[40 17  6]';'[40 18  5]'];
ax = axis; 
axis(axis);
Yl = ax(3:4); 
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')

t = text(Xt,Yl(1)*ones(1,length(Xt)),algos(1:length(days),:));

set(t,'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','top','Rotation',90,'Fontsize',10);
```

[image: chart]

I want to completely remove the original labels on the x axis, however my x tick labels are not completely turning off.

**I am using Matlab R2014a.**

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error (MATLAB 2017a). The xlabels correctly disappear for me, and are replaced by your text.

Comment: It works fine for me too in R2016b.

Comment: you can use rate=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15];

Comment: The xlabels beneath the [18 36 9] is 2 which is not desired

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I am using  R2014a but its not working

Comment: It also works fine for me in 2015b, but I have provided a better method for axis labelling below anyway.

Comment: @user7341333: Does replacing `set(gca,'XTickLabel','')` with `set(ax,'XTickLabel','')` help? (In this case `ax` is the first one returned by `plotyy`, not the one you overwrote by doing `ax = axis;`)

Comment: @gnvoice Oh yes thankyou very much it actually did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gnovice points out, your issue is with the `gca` axis object not being the one with all of the labels! I am leaving my answer here because it builds on that solution with a neater method to align labels to your plot items.

Solve the original problem (as gnovice says) by using

```
 [ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(days, nash, days, rate, 'bar', 'plot');
 set(ax,'XTickLabel','') % should work!
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

However, it seems like you're trying to replace the x tick labels with a `text` object, and I'm not sure why. **Simply change the labels to be the text labels!**

```
[ax, h1, h2] = plotyy(days, nash, days, rate, 'bar', 'plot');
% NOTE: I've made this a cell array by using curly braces { }
algos = {'[3  36 24]';'[18 36  9]';'[33 24  6]';'[33 12 18]';'[36 17 10]';'[33 20 10]';'[34 24  5]';'[34 12 17]';'[34 20  9]';'[48 12  3]';'[48 10  5]'; '[48  6  9]';'[40 20  3]';'[40 17  6]';'[40 18  5]'};
% Set the text labels as axis labels
set(ax, 'xticklabel', algos);
% Rotate (as of Matlab 2014b)
set(ax, 'xticklabelrotation', 90);
```

---

Using 2014a, you will not be able to use `xticklabelrotation`. Instead, you may find the [Rotate Tick Label](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label) function in the File Exchange useful. This function does essentially do the same thing as you are trying, but is neatly packaged and well reviewed.

Once downloaded, this would simply be called instead of the last line above by

```
rotateticklabel(ax, 90); % Could even just do rotateticklabel(gca) as 90 is default
```

Output using the text as labels like shown in my code:

[image: output 2]

Comment: But i am using matlab 2014a therefore i am using the text approach.......because the xticklabelrotation works in matlab 2014b I cannot use it

Comment: I have made a further edit since I saw that is the version you are using

Comment: I have tried using the following code but giving me the same error

Comment: set(gca,'XTick',1:15) 
    set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'[3  36 24]';'[18 36  9]';'[33 24  6]';'[33 12 
    18]';'[36 17 10]';'[33 20 10]';'[34 24  5]';'[34 12 17]';'[34 20  9]';'[48 12  
    3]';'[48 10  5]'; '[48  6  9]';'[40 20  3]';'[40 17  6]';'[40 18  5]'}) 
    th=rotateticklabel(gca,90);

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error in R2013a. It turns out that your line:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')
```

only removes *some* of your x axis labels. If you change this to:

```
set(ax,'XTickLabel','')
```

and move it up to before you redefine `ax`, so that the `ax` it refers to is the one returned by [`plotyy`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html), it will remove all of the x axis labels for you.

This comes from the fact that there are two axes created by `plotyy`, but [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) will only ever refer to one. You can see that *both* axes have values set for their [`'XTickLabel'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e51535) property by doing the following after your call to `plotyy`:

```
>> get(ax(1),'XTickLabel')  % Get x tick labels for the first axes

ans =

1 
2
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
11
12
13
14
15

>> get(ax(2),'XTickLabel')  % Get x tick labels for the second axes

ans =

0 
2 
4 
6 
8 
10
12
14
16
```

Using `gca` to change the x tick labels will only change one axes, not both. Hence, you should use the `ax` output from `plotyy` to modify both axes simultaneously.

**NOTE:** As of R2016a `plotyy` is no longer recommended, and you should instead use [`yyaxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html).

Comment: @gnvoice It helped Thanks a lot